# How can I remove my "login password" but keep my "ssh password"?

Tags: ssh, networking, password

Every time I restart my computer I have to enter my password to login.

I want this gone.

So everytime I restart, it doesn't ask me for my password.

But still, at the same time, if there are incoming ssh connections, I want them to only get in if they have a password, lets say the password is "bob123"

So in summary, I **don't** want a login password, but I **do** want a password when people try to ssh to my computer.

Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on what graphical user interface you have (if you want a login into graphical user interface). There is a guide how to do that in GNOME:

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en

Comment: Will this still prompt ssh passwords?

Comment: Yes. The ssh will always prompt for password, even if there would not be any and if it would not accept the empty password.